# Schedule module producing weird output

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

This piece of code is not behaving the way I would expect: instead of printing 1, 2, 3, ...; the code returns just random numbers (I've tried closing everything and restarting it, but it always yields random numbers.)

```
import schedule
import time

a = 0


def count_fun():
    global a
    for i in range(1000):
        a += i
    return a


def print_a():
    print(a)


schedule.every(3).seconds.do(count_fun)
schedule.every(3).seconds.do(print_a)



while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not printing random numbers, it's printing `k * sum(range(1000)` for `k` in 1, 2, 3, ...

Your expectation that this should print the integers 1, 2, 3, etc, is incorrect. `a` is not incremented by 1 on each iteration, it is updated with the value `sum(range(1000))` on each iteration. *The whole for loop runs each time.*

Running the code you have here prints

```
499500
999000
1498500
1998000
```

Some quick arithmetic should confirm that the difference between successive elements there is `499500`, or `sum(range(1000))`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That makes sense. Do you have any suggestions as to what to try to get the code to print 1, 2, 3, etc.? I tried to re-write the function using `yield` and then execute `next` with schedule, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: To print that sequence of numbers, you need to just _assign_ to `a`, not add to it. I.e., `a = i` inside the loop. `+=` is in-place addition.